# Retain Navigator view state when switching working sets in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, working-set

When switching working sets in Eclipse, the tree in the Navigator View collapses. Is there any way to stop that collapse and have the view retain the tree in its open position?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the state of the nodes of the Navigator are part of the state of the workspace being saved when closing.

A much safer (are more powerful) solution would be to use **[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)**

[image]

> You can focus navigator views (e.g. Package Explorer, Project Explorer, Navigator) by toggling the "Focus on Active Task" button in the toolbar.
>   **When focused, the view will show only the resources that are "interesting" for the currently active task**.

So when you reopen your workspace and select a task to work on, only the relevant classes/methods are displayed, in the state they were left.